# Use ramda `sequence` to traverse a dictionary

Tags: ramda.js, fantasyland

How can I use ramda's [`sequence`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#sequence) to traverse a dictionary?

Given the following dictionary

```
cars = {color: ['yellow', 'red'], year: [2017], model: ['coup', 'sedan']}
```

I'd like to produce the traversed result

```
all_cars = [
    {color: 'yellow', year: 2017, model: 'coup'},
    {color: 'yellow', year: 2017, model: 'sedan'},
    {color: 'red', year: 2017, model: 'coup'},
    {color: 'red', year: 2017, model: 'sedan'}
]
```

Using `R.sequence` results in a list of an empty list

```
R.sequence(R.of, cars)
[[]]
```

If I traverse a list instead of a dictionary it produces the correct cartesian product, but the results are (of course) lists instead of dictionaries.

```
R.sequence(R.of, [['yellow', 'red'], [2017], ['coup', 'sedan']])
[["yellow", 2017, "coup"], ["yellow", 2017, "sedan"], ["red", 2017, "coup"], ["red", 2017, "sedan"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do this, one involving `sequence`, and the other not.

This one uses your `sequence(of)` call above:

```
const convert = lift(map)(
  compose(zipObj, keys), 
  compose(sequence(of), values)
)

const all_cars = convert(cars);
```

The other was built by my usual technique of keep changing the output with one transformation after another until I get to what I want:

```
const combine = pipe(
  toPairs,
  map(apply(useWith(map, [objOf, identity]))),
  reduce(xprod, [[]]),
  map(flatten),
  map(mergeAll)
)

const all_cars = combine(cars)
```

This might be made a little clearer by introducing a crossproduct across multiple lists:

```
const xproduct = reduce(pipe(xprod, map(unnest)), [[]])

const combine = pipe(
  toPairs,
  map(apply(useWith(map, [objOf, identity]))),
  xproduct,
  map(mergeAll)
)
```

The second version is what I came up with on first trying the problem.  Then when I looked to see what you'd tried, I got that first version.  That first version looks cleaner to me, although most of the individual steps in the second one are trivial.  But since there is one non-trivial step in there, the first one seems an overall winner.

You can see [the first](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?let%20cars%20%3D%20%7Bcolor%3A%20%5B%27yellow%27%2C%20%27red%27%5D%2C%20year%3A%20%5B2017%5D%2C%20model%3A%20%5B%27coup%27%2C%20%27sedan%27%5D%7D%0A%0Alift%28map%29%28%0A%20%20compose%28zipObj%2C%20keys%29%2C%20%0A%20%20compose%28sequence%28of%29%2C%20values%29%0A%29%28cars%29%0A) or [the second](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?let%20cars%20%3D%20%7Bcolor%3A%20%5B%27yellow%27%2C%20%27red%27%5D%2C%20year%3A%20%5B2017%5D%2C%20model%3A%20%5B%27coup%27%2C%20%27sedan%27%5D%7D%0A%0Aconst%20xproduct%20%3D%20reduce%28pipe%28xprod%2C%20map%28unnest%29%29%2C%20%5B%5B%5D%5D%29%0A%0Aconst%20combine%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20toPairs%2C%0A%20%20map%28apply%28useWith%28map%2C%20%5BobjOf%2C%20identity%5D%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20reduce%28xprod%2C%20%5B%5B%5D%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28flatten%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28mergeAll%29%0A%29%0A%0Acombine%28cars%29%0A) on the Ramda REPL.

Comment: That works, but surely there should be a fantasy-land `Traversable` instance for dictionaries to take advantage of.

Comment: Ramda has [debated this](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2046) numerous times.  It's hard even to get anything foldable against an object when you could have a non-commutative function and you still want to consider `{a:1, b:2}` and `{b:2, a:1}` to be equal.

Comment: Crazy. Considering `{a:1, b:2} = {b:2, a:1}` doesn't preclude choosing a canonical order for `Traversable`.

Comment: I would like to choose a canonical order, probably by sorting the keys.  But the language dictates another order: the order the keys were added.  We've simply hit a major sticking point here: some people want to keep the language order, which means our equality needs work.  I'd rather keep that value equality and choose a canonical order.  It's very hard to get consensus.  And I want to fix `keys` and `values` too.

Comment: Or provide more than one `Traversable` instance and a way to tag/wrap dictionaries with the order to use.

Comment: That's an interesting possibility.  I'll have to think on that a bit.  But it might be a solution to our dilemma.